# how to send email from php application to a local email

Tags: php, email, local

I have a local network in the company with a mail server, how can i make php application built locally on the server to send and email to a local email address?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just send it with the [mail](http://php.net/mail) function. It's up to the system administrator to configure the MTA properly. In your example the MTA on the server would be configured to deliver mail for certain addresses locally instead of sending them out to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

configure an smtp for the local server, and send using PEAR.

[Example](http://www.webkami.com/programming/php/php-pear-mail-intro/sending-pear-mail-using-php-function-error.html)